# What can cause an inability to set QRYTIMLMT in DB2 from .NET?

Tags: ado.net, timeout, db2, .net-4.5

We are using IBM's data provider from C# .NET 4.5 to query an i Series DB2 database. Normally this works very well, but for some queries, DB2 reports error "SQL0666 - SQL query exceeds specified time limit or storage limit".

I have tried [setting the command timeout to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111467/sql0666-sql-query-exceeds-specified-time-limit-or-storage-limit), but to no effect. I have also tried to execute, in the manner explained [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86207/iDb-Connection-How-to-cancel-a-long-running-query), the CHGQRYA command to set the QRYTIMLMT value to *NOMAX (or some other large value), but seemingly to no effect. However, if I use the same command to set the QRYSTGLMT (storage limit), it takes effect. Thus, I know that I am using the command correctly, and that it gets interpreted and executed by the database.

So, what can cause my inability to set the QRYTIMLMT value?

Also, our "DBA" has set the limit to *NOMAX on his end, and for queries not running through the .NET provider, everything works fine.

We're using IBM's Client Tools version 6r1 with service pack SI42423.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after lots of testing, I found the problem.

We're using the DeriveParameters() method to set the parameter types correctly, and if this method is called before setting CommandTimeout, the latter has no effect(!). The solution was to reverse the ordering of these statements.